# Why 95%CI of OR in tbl_regression (and manual 95%CI) is different from 95%CI from logistic.display and does not match p-value?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, confidence-interval, gtsummary

If I want to perform logistic regression, I can use three different ways:

- manually :

```
fit1 <- (glm(outcome~A+B,family=binomial,data=database))
summary(fit1)
exp(confint(fit1))
exp(coefficients(fit1)
```

- function `tbl_regression` from `gtsumary` package

```
fit1 <- (glm(outcome~A+B,family=binomial,data=database))
tbl_regression(fit1, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

- function `logistic.display` from `epiDisplay` package

```
fit1 <- (glm(outcome~A+B,family=binomial,data=database))
logistic.display(fit1)
```

Adjusted OR and p-value are the same with the three methods.

But I am surprised to see that 95%CI from `tbl_regression` and manual calculation are different from 95%CI from `logistic.display`...

[image]

However, only the 95%CI from the `logistic.display` function matches the p-value (whitch should include 1 if p-value > 0.05).

Does anybody know why?

Comment: it should be exp(x)/(1+exp(x)) , not exp(x)

Comment: I still does not understand why 95% CI in tbl_regression and in logistic.display are different? 95% CI from logistic.display seems to be right according to not significant pvalue (CI contains 1).... Maybe @DanielDSjoberg could help us?

Comment: The gtsummary package matches the base R summary function and the broom::tidy() function. You need to reach out to the authors of the epiDisplay package to identify why their CI does not match any other. IF you provide a reproducible example, meaning code and data that I can run on my machine, I may be able to provide more clear direction. But only if that is provided.

Comment: FYI, I ran the example from the help file of `epiDisplay::logistic.display()`, and it prints curde and adjusted odds ratios, along with p-values from Wald and LRT methods. My guess is you're mixing the univariate and multivariable models.

Comment: The data can be found here: https://jpst.it/2tJ0s

Comment: the code ```dataB <- read.table("clipboard", header = T, dec = ".", sep = "\t")``` ```fit1 <- glm(outcome~A+D,family=binomial,data=dataB)``` ```tbl_regression(fit1, exponentiate = T)``` return 95%CI which does not contains 1, but the pvalue is > 0.05 for variable A... I can't find where is the mistake!

Comment: this line does not run `dataB <- read.table("clipboard", header = T, dec = ".", sep = "\t")`

Comment: You have to copy the data first (and then run the first line, which will paste the data and create the dataframe)

Comment: The CI method and the p-value method don't always align. (You can google the reasons this may happen.) If you want your CI to match the p-value in this case, you can use Wald confidence intervals, and they can be calculated with `confint.default()`. If you're using `tbl_regression()`, there is an example here: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/vetted_models.html#examples

Comment: I would rather prefer to have the pvalue matched on the CI, is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231175/discussion-between-daniel-d-sjoberg-and-b-slash).